# No such column error while inserting in SQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, android-sqlite

CODE:

```
//creating an sqlite query and setting column names 
along with data types.
String query = "CREATE TABLE tableMon (notes TEXT)";

//calling a exec sql method to execute sql query
db.execSQL(query);

//after adding....passing content values to the table
String insert = "INSERT INTO tableMon (notes) VALUES ( 
" + values + " )";
db.execSQL(insert);
```

ERROR:
tableMon has no column named notes in "INSERT INTO tableMon (notes) VALUES ( notes=hello )"

I have tried adding and removing spaces near the column name and adding variables instead direct use of table name and column name.
Though! didn't get any expected result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is that the value being inserted is non-numeric and thus must be enclosed in single quotes. So:-

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO tableMon (notes) VALUES ('" + values + "' )";
```

However, the above code is susceptible to SQL Injection So it would be better to use:-

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO tableMon (notes) VALUES (?)";
db.execSQL(insert,new String[]{values};
```

In this case the value will be suitable enclosed when it is bound by SQLite binding.

However, another approach is to use the SQLiteDatabse [`insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method. This has the advantages that

- it builds the underlying SQL, and
- binds values,
- and returns the rowid of the inserted row or -1 if the row could not be inserted.

In your case you could use:-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("notes",values);
long result = db.insert("tableMon",null,cv);
```

Here is a working demo:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(this.getDatabasePath("example.db").getPath(),null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableMon (notes TEXT)");
        String values = "notes=hello";
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableMon (notes) VALUES('" + values + "')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableMon (notes) VALUES(?)",new String[]{values});
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("notes",values);
        db.insert("tableMon",null,cv);
    }
}
```

- Note the use of `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, which will circumvent the error if the table already exists.

The result, via Android Studio's ***App Inspection*** ,when installed and run (first time, subsequent runs would add another set of 3 rows):-

[image]

i.e. 3 rows have been inserted using each of the fixes.

Comment: This is still not a good solution. Prepared statements exist, and are far better for arbitrary input

Comment: @MikeT your solution didn't worked for me.

Comment: @MikeT still getting the same error

Comment: @DhwaniPatel All 3 solutions work as can be seen with the working demo. Suggest that you uninstall the App and rerun.